# GORM transactions in a non-transactional GroovyTestCase integration test

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, transactions, grails-orm

I have an integration test with `static transactional = false`, and I am trying to use a dynamic/detatched finder in one of the test functions, but I'm not being successful at it. The exception I'm getting is below.  I'm unable to fix it by simply putting the `@Transactional` annotation on the function.

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

I'm going out on a limb here, but would one have to use the withTransaction closure?  I'm not sure if I want to go this route as I don't want all of my related items to have to use eager fetching in this particular domain class.

e.g.
`SomeDomainClass.withTransaction { // some logic. }`

Is there another way to get the session available to Hibernate for this single test function?

Answer (score 0):

you can try `SomeDomainClass.withNewSession { ... }` if that changes anything to you